# JQuery AppendTo Title attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm following this tutorial [Drag Drop Inventory in Jquery](http://qoate.com/231/create-drag-and-drop-inventory-using-jquery/)

and i'm having a problem. In the demo that accompanies the tutorial, the author uses this code :

```
item.attr('src',drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class',drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
```

While this works great in recreating the img element, it does not copy the title attribute( i want to copy that because it's important for my tooltips).

I've changed this code like :

```
item.attr('title',drag_item.attr('title')).attr('src',drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class',drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
```

which should work i think, but it does not. When i change drag_item.attr('title') to something static like "hello", it works, but the attr func does not return the title.

My html is like :

```
<div id="inventory" style="width:300px; height:150px; margin:10px; padding:15px; border:1px solid black; display:block; clear:both;">
 <% @inv_items.each do |i| %>
   <% w = Weapon.find_by_id(i.item_id) %>

      <img class='weapons' src= "/images/weapons/<%=h w.imageName %>" title="<%= setWeaponTitleForTooltip(w, i) %>" />
 <% end %>
</div>
```

The html is actually an erb template. Do you have any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours code seems to be fine.  [**`working demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/hWQ5U/)  i.e. derived from example given in above link. It is also copying title attribute.

Comment: That is really weird :/ Maybe it's something related to jquery tooltips or some rails caveat ? I''m taking a closer look. I mark your question as correct, because the example works. Thanx ;)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Firebug or another debugger to see if there are any errors? The code looks good, but I can't imagine the resulting HTML of your erb-template. Maybe the resulting title-attribute of your image tags are empty.

Comment: hey Patrick, thanx for the reply. Yes, i'm using firebug and there is actually no error. However, it refuses to grab the title. I'm actually checking the generated source, and after the appendTo, the new element is like : <img style="position: relative;" class="weapons ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging" src="/images/weapons/morningStar.jpg" title="">. That is, no title attached :/

Comment: So it's a problem in the erb-template. I don't know erb, but it looks to me as if you have some kind of a for-each-loop there and try to access the w-variable inside the loop asking for index i from the loop with setWeaponTitleForTooltip(w, i) - which most probably would work outside the loop, but not inside. 

what output gives setWeaponTitleForTooltip(inv_items, i) - maybe that works.